# Pass parameters to jQuery $.get

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I can't seems to find solution to my problem here. All I want to do is to pass parameters to jQuery `$.get` to call MVC controller. I don't want to use `$.ajax`.

Here is my code:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("MonthlyChart", "Chart")', function (data) {
    chartData = "<tr id='trChart'><td colspan='5'>" + data + "</td></tr>";
    $('#tblDetail tr:nth-child(' + rowIndex + ')').after(chartData);
});
```

How can I pass parameter in it?
(This is not a duplicate question. I tried many described here. but it can't seems to work.)

Comment: Read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: @Blender Take a good look before voting down. it does not solve my problem. I am also using Razor MVC,which is not directly accessable in jQuery.

Comment: I didn't vote your question down. You're going to have to clarify what you mean by "parameter".

Comment: @Blender I am sorry to doubt you, I just want to pass data just like in $.ajax.   like $.get('@Url.Action("MonthlyChart", "Chart")', {parameter}, function (data))

Comment: Just like the second example in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your parameters as an object in second argument.

```
$.get('somepage.php', {
    'param1':'value1',
    'param2':'value2'
}, function (data) {
    chartData = "<tr id='trChart'><td colspan='5'>" + data + "</td></tr>";
    $('#tblDetail tr:nth-child(' + rowIndex + ')').after(chartData);
});
```